# I installed then deleted gnome and ubuntu desktop, now stuff isn't working correctly

Tags: unity

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

and realized it wasn't what I was after. I then did:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome*
```

and it jacked stuff up. I got my system back usable with:

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

from recovery mode and installed the `fgrlx` drivers to get my panel back. I used ATI drivers before, but they aren't showing up under additional drivers. So, I installed them from the AMD website per googled instructions. Unity still isn't working like it was. Ubuntu Tweak doesn't have as many options, my workspace switcher looks different, the top bar is more gnomish looking, and the dash is about 2/3 the screen instead of full screen.

How can I get my desktop back to out of the box settings?  I'd like to keep all my installed apps and files though.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to reinstall Ubuntu if you have an installation disc or if you can make one; it should still keep all of your files and usually keeps all your programs.
Just boot into the installation disc, and when it asks for what to do, simply select "Reinstall Ubuntu."
If you don't see that option or you don't want to go that route, then try this:

> sudo apt-get build-dep ubuntu-desktop; sudo dpkg-reconfigure ubuntu-desktop

Comment: This isn't an option on my live disk.  The reinstall options says it will delete everything...  Anyone else?